# multiple line to single line in ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have three data fields that I am displaying in a table in SSRS 2008 R2.

Unique_Number
Communication_Type  (this will contain Tel, Fax, email)
Communication_data  (Contains the data for the above)

Not all unique numbers will have all communication types. i.e. they may only have a telephone.

My data displays in a table as multiple rows of data:

```
Unique_Number.....Communication_Type....Communication_Data

1..............................Tel..................................12345

1..............................Fax..................................12346 

1..............................Email...............................a@b.com

2..............................Tel...................................23456

3..............................Fax..................................45678
```

I would like my table to look like:

```
Unique Number...Tel........Fax.........Email

1..........................12345...12346.....a@b.com

2..........................23456...blank......blank

3..........................blank....45678.....blank
```

I can hide the multiple rows by using the row visibility function but then of course I lose some of the data.

I have also used this function in a cell labelled Telephone:
 `=iif(Fields!Communication_Type.Value = "Tel", Fields!Communication_Data.Value, "")`

This sort of works except the data for each comms type is displayed on a separate line.

How can I make this work using the query designer?

Comment: was hoping to use a function within a table in the report designer

Comment: There's no way to do what you're looking for by just using SSRS Functions you need to modify the query and you wont need to use SSRS functions at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a pivot in your query you won't need to do any expressions or anything. That would be much better in regards to performance as well since everything will be done in the query rather than in the report which will take additional time to render all the expressions that you're thinking to add if you don't do a pivot.

Try this as the query dataset implementing a pivot on the rows/columns:

```
SELECT unique_number,Email,Fax,Tel FROM (
select unique_number,communication_type,communication_data
from *tablename*
)t
pivot (max(communication_data) for communication_type in ([Email],[Fax],[Tel]))piv;
```

Demo Fiddle:[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aab80/1)